# How to simulate AGV charging time?

Tags: anylogic

I am setting up a flow with an AGV transporter fleet. After 5 hours working they need to charge for 45 minutes. Please tell me how this can be implemented.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. What have you tried already? Always helpful to see what work you already did so we can tune our reply to that ;-) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Indeed, it is hard to tell if this is really a `programming question` (i.e., do you need help with one specific problem you encountered along the way) or a `data science` question, which is more generally asking how an analysis might be carried out (or if, indeed, it is at all possible). For data science questions there is separate forum. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can explore [this example](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/68374513-8155-46d2-98bd-e308481afb42?mode=SETTINGS)